# High rate of object creation/destruction - Garbage collector too late causing slow downs x64

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

My application needs to buffer about 300mb of images coming in through high-speed cameras.
There is a queue where oldest images are disposed and new images are added.

Due to this cycle nature many objects are being created and many disposed. I am using ConcurrentQueues to handle all of that.

Application performance is great, but once the 12GB system memory are used, it degrades and only then the Garbage collection seems to kick in bringing the memory load back down to around 300mb.

I have run ANTS memory profiler on it and it doesn't seem like there are any leaks.

**Is calling Garbage collection myself an option here?**

Also, I have the idea of reusing byte arrays to store the images but that would be quite a rewrite, and I would only follow that route if the rest fails...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this all managed memory?

Comment: yes, all in managed memory. mostly byte arrays

Comment: Image data is normally stored in unmanaged memory.  Your question is too poorly documented to tell but GC.AddMemoryPressure() might help.

Comment: Consider using the server garbage collector. Add `<gcServer enabled=true>` to your App.config file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx. Also, be sure you're calling `Dispose` on those bitmaps.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I was trying the gcServer  variable but couldn't notice any difference. I was reading up on the addmemorypressure also but didn't try it out because in parallel I was also going the route I suggested myself. Turns out it wasn't that hard and I'm now staying at a constant 300mb memory usage by reusing the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The main disadvantage of calling GC.Collect is that you might burn more CPU than you need to. You also prematurely promote objects to higher generations.

In your case it is a CPU/memory tradeoff that you can safely take.

You might also consider limiting the amount of memory that your process can use. Windows can impose such a limit with Job Objects. You can enlist your process into a limited Job and Windows will deny the CLR memory. The CLR will then collect to make room.